# Wordpress posting object terms as children?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

My WordPress is having some issues, I cannot seem to figure out. I have a custom post type with several custom taxonomies, all of them work fine except when I try and associate values within a given taxonomy, I will explain.

So to my understanding when adding custom terms into custom posts you need several things. First check if the term exists using term_exists function, this returns an array which contains the term_id (assuming it is found) if it is not, you use `wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args());` then after it is inserted you can associate it with a post. `wp_set_object_terms ( $post_id, $valueOfTerm, $taxonomy);` and this works for everything. However I am trying to get a layered taxonomy, volume and issue. So I need a volume number that will hold several issue numbers. In the image you can see the box that is getting checked now, and the boxes I want to get checked below.

[image: dialog screenshot]

The current code I am using is:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $volumeNumber , $volume_taxonomy);
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $issueNumber , $volume_taxonomy);
```

I basically don't know how to say the term I want to enter is a sub term of a taxonomy. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: We might need to see some more code. How are you setting $issueNumber?

Comment: $issueNumber and $volumeNumber are both just integers I get from parsing and XML file earlier in the program